# Sum infinite sum for a complex variable not in the integers

Tags: complex-analysis

i'm trying to sum the series

$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}(n + a)^{-2}$ for a complex number $a \not\in \mathbb{Z}$

without any luck. I am not sure how to approach this question, other than it should be tricks using laurent series and residuals i think.

Would love some help and tips to attack the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's well-known that $$\sin \pi x=\pi x\prod_{n\ne 0}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right).$$Taking the log-derivative, $$\pi\cot \pi x=\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n\ne 0}\frac{-2x}{n^2-x^2}=\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n\ne 0}\left(\frac{1}{n+x}-\frac{1}{n-x}\right).$$Splitting the infinite sum, $$\pi\cot\pi x=\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{x+n}+\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{x-n}=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\frac{1}{x+n}.$$Finally, take $-\frac{d}{dx}$ at $x=a$: $$\pi^2\csc^2\pi a=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}.$$This result makes obvious why we had the restriction $a\not\in\Bbb Z$ to begin with.